# PHP Inserting datetime from form

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, insert

I have a form where users need to select two dates, one being just the date and one being date and time. I have a basic form with the two fields where users have to input date like `2014-02-02` and time datetime like `2014-02-02 10:20:00`, the form validation for this works great.

However the problem comes when inserting the values to the database. This is what I have:

```
<?php
class Quote
{
  public $job_deadline = null;
  public $job_dispatchdate = null;
}

public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['job_deadline'] ) ) $this->job_deadline = (int) $data['job_deadline'];
    if ( isset( $data['job_dispatchdate'] ) ) $this->job_dispatchdate = (int) $data['job_dispatchdate'];
    //if ( isset( $data['job_dispatchdate'] ) ) $this->job_dispatchdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($data['job_dispatchdate']));
}

public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params );

       if ( isset($params['job_deadline']) ) {
      $job_deadline = explode ( '-', $params['job_deadline'] );

      if ( count($job_deadline) == 3 ) {
        list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $job_deadline;
        $this->job_deadline = gmmktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
      }
    }

    if ( isset($params['job_dispatchdate']) ) {
        $job_deadline = $params['job_dispatchdate'];
        list ( $y, $m, $d, $h, $i, $s ) = $job_dispatchdate;
        $this->job_dispatchdate = gmmktime ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $y, $m, $d, $h, $i, $s );
    }

    /*
    if ( isset($params['job_dispatchdate']) ) {
        $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($params['job_dispatchdate']));
    }
    */
}

public function insertjob() {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

    //$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($params['job_dispatchdate']));  USING $datetime inplace of FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_dispatchdate) and removing st for job_dispatchdate

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (job_deadline, job_dispatchdate) 
    VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_deadline), FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_dispatchdate))";               
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":job_deadline", $this->job_deadline, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":job_dispatchdate", $this->job_dispatchdate, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $this->job_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $inserted_id = $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

The `job_deadline` inserts fine, the problem is with the `job_dispatchdate`. The commented out sections are things I have tried but also different work. I ever get no insert so the field appears as `NULL` or some date like `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

**Can anyone help me with inserting datetime.**

Thanks in advance.

Ian

---EDIT---

```
<?php
class Quote
{
  public $job_deadline = null;
  public $job_dispatchdate = null;
}

public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['job_deadline'] ) ) $this->job_deadline = (int) $data['job_deadline'];
    if ( isset( $data['job_dispatchdate'] ) ) $this->job_dispatchdate = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\|\+\#\"\@\%\?\!\&\:\;\£\$\/\\\(\n) a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['job_dispatchdate'] );
}

public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params );

       if ( isset($params['job_deadline']) ) {
      $job_deadline = explode ( '-', $params['job_deadline'] );

      if ( count($job_deadline) == 3 ) {
        list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $job_deadline;
        $this->job_deadline = gmmktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
      }
    }

    if ( isset($params['job_dispatchdate']) ) {
        $job_deadline = $params['job_dispatchdate'];
        list ( $y, $m, $d, $h, $i, $s ) = $job_dispatchdate;
        $this->job_dispatchdate = gmmktime ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $y, $m, $d, $h, $i, $s );
    }
}

public function insertjob() {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    //$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($params['job_dispatchdate']));  USING $datetime inplace of FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_dispatchdate) and removing st for job_dispatchdate
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (job_deadline, job_dispatchdate) 
    VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_deadline), FROM_UNIXTIME(:job_dispatchdate))";               
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":job_deadline", $this->job_deadline, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":job_dispatchdate", $this->job_dispatchdate, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $this->job_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $inserted_id = $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

Based on comments I have changed code to this. and set field in DB to string Varchar but to no avail.

Comment: in which format the date is comming as param for job_dispatchdate ?

Comment: as in? from the form? the field is date.

Comment: PDO::PARAM_INT it should be PDO::PARAM_STR for job_dispatchdate

Comment: `(int) $data['job_dispatchdate']` looks fishy to me

Answer (score 0):

```
 $st->bindValue( ":job_dispatchdate", $this->job_dispatchdate, PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

Should be

```
 $st->bindValue( ":job_dispatchdate", $this->job_dispatchdate, PDO::PARAM_STR)
```

**Suggestion** : Better store all your date in mysql in unix timestamp format.

**EDIT 2** :Change your job_dispatche column type to **STRING** if it is in **INT** type

Comment: Why is this? I have tryed it and still doesnt work. job_deadline uses PDO::PARAM_INT and that works fine.

Comment: because date with time format is not considered as integer

Comment: my suggestion would be better store date filed as unix timestamp format in DB , it will sove all your overhead

Comment: ok, so will i need to change 

if ( isset( $data['job_deadline'] ) ) $this->job_deadline = (int) $data['job_deadline']; 

to something like 

if ( isset( $data['job_dispatchdate'] ) ) $this->job_dispatchdate = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\|\+\#\"\@\%\?\!\&\:\;\£\$\/\\\(\n) a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['job_dispatchdate'] );

Comment: I have updated my original post with some changes lie you mention, but i'm still not any closer.

Comment: what is your dispatch date column data type ? ??

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($params['job_dispatchdate']) ) {
        $job_deadline = $params['job_dispatchdate'];
        $this->job_dispatchdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $job_deadline ));
}
```

This seemed to fix it. Thank you all